# How to enable a cgi-perl-script to do things with root-authorization?

Tags: perl, cgi, authorization

I am root on my own webserver and I did write a perl-script for maintaining my website. Called from a browser this script displayes a user-interface for maintainance. To be able to start this script from my browser, I must enter a username and a password, so nobody but me can run this script.

I want that this script renames some files on the server when I click on the according button. From the perl-script I call the shell-command `` `mv oldFilename newFilename` ``, but nothing happens. Apache's error log displays this message:

> [*timestring*] [error] [client *n.n.n.n*] mv: cannot move *oldFilename* to *newFilename*: Permission denied, referer: *referrer*

*filename*'s owner is root, permissions are set to 0644 (everybody can read, only root can write)

What is the best solution for this problem? Is there a better way than changing the files permissions to 0666? I want to refrain from changing the permissions. I would prefere a solution where the perl-script sayes to the shell something like: "*Dear shell, here is the password for root. Now please rename file X to Y!*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this the exact problem that Unix groups were meant to solve? Set file permission to `0664`, directory permissions to `0775`, and assign the files and directories to a group that the webserver user belongs to.

Comment: You don't necessarily want to him to change all directories in the system to `0775` and all files to `0664`, though, right?

Answer (score 1):

Don't ignore security. Use [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo).

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a Perl web site with html pages and Java script. All the program files are protected with root ownership.

Even if you limit access to this program through a username and password on the web site, then root should own the program `chown root:root <full-path-to-your-program-name>`, and the program file should be protected `chmod 755 <full-path-to-your-program-name>`.